# USB stick needs to be PXE bootable

Tags: bootable-media, pxe

I've created a bootable USB using Syslinux and Diskpart. The USB contains Windows-based software.  Unfortunately for me, I now need to be able to PXE boot other desktops using only the USB stick.  Please help as it isn't quite clear how to do this. I have searched various sites like Serva's, Tiny PXE Server, and various sites through Google. Also when I tried to PXE boot a client, neither Serva or Tiny PXE Server are serving out anything via TFTP. I've added an exception to my Windows Firewall for port 69 as well.

To further clarify, I need the bootable USB stick to be the bootable image file that is going to be served through the network for PXE-enabled clients that are trying to PXE boot.

Comment: PXE boot means you will boot the machine from the network through the network card (which has to be PXE enabled), so where does the USB stick come in? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am aware that PXE boot means that a server shoots a bootable image over the network to any clients looking to boot off of the network.  I need the bootable USB stick to be the bootable image that is going to be shot through the network for PXE enabled clients that are looking to PXE boot.

Comment: The USb contents need to be put on your PXE TFTP server so that your PXE clients know what image they're booting...

Comment: I have tried copying the files over to the appropriate folder but that didn't work at all.  I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific. What did not work at all? I just downloaded serva and did a test with a CentOS7 image. It worked fine.

Comment: Please have a look at [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Then, after reading and understanding it, tell us about what you want to achieve in addition to what you’ve tried. We still don’t know what’s really on the USB drive. Is it Windows PE? What does the “Windows-based software” do? How do you use the USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how you created the content of your pen-drive.
i.e. many Windows based tools use today a Windows PE based approach and that is easily ported to a PXE server like Serva.
The problems appear if your application relies on loading "discrete" components from the pen-drive, remember on a PXE situation those components must be "net-retrieved" from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the developer and unfortunately found out that it will not be possible to convert the image into something that would be pxe bootable.  Thanks for all your help